# Selecting 2 biggest NIP from the table

Tags: sql, database

How do I select the 2 of the biggest NIP from the table? Can someone help me? I only manage to get the highest one.

[This is my table]

[image: 1]

I've tried the TOP function but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag your database

Comment: And explain what’s not working! Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote your query as you posted, it should just be to write SELECT TOP 2 instead of SELECT 2 TOP

Comment: I just tried it and it still wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using MySQL , the syntax is like this :

```
Select *
From tablename
Order by nip desc limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want the longests alamat's?

So order them by descending length.

**MS Sql Server**

```
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY LEN(alamat) DESC
```

**MySql**

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(alamat) DESC
LIMIT 2
```